# Force Move semantics

Tags: c++11, move-semantics

I'm trying to use move semantics (just as an experiment).
Here is my code:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(size_t c): count(c) {
        data = new int[count];
    }



    MyClass( MyClass&& src) : count(src.count) {
        data = src.data;
        src.count = 0;
        src.data = nullptr;
    }

    void operator=( MyClass&& src) {
        data = src.data;
        count = src.count;
        src.count = 0;
        src.data = nullptr;
    }




    ~MyClass() {
        if (data != nullptr)
            delete[] data;
    }

    int* get_data() const {
        return data;
    }

    size_t get_count() const {
        return count;
    }

private:

    MyClass(const MyClass& src) : count(src.count) {
        data = new int[src.count];
        memcpy(data, src.data, sizeof(int)*src.count);
    }

    void operator=(const MyClass& src) {
        count = src.count;
        data = new int[src.count];
        memcpy(data, src.data, sizeof(int)*src.count);
    }


    int* data;
    size_t count;
};


int main()
{
    MyClass mc(150);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < mc.get_count(); ++i)
        mc.get_data()[i] = i;
    MyClass &&mc2 = std::move(mc);

    return 0;
}
```

But std::move does not move mc to mc2, it just copies (copyies pointer as it is). If I remove copy constructor compiler generates it for MyClass.

How can I force move semantics to be used? How can I make it to be used in such constructions:

```
MyClass mc2(mc); //Move, not copy
-or-
MyClass mc2 = mc; //Move, not copy
```

I tried to use a '&&' operator to explicitely mark rvalue, but, of cause, it didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're declaring `m2` as a *reference,* not as a value. So it still refers to what it was initialised with, namely `m1`. You wanted this:

```
MyClass mc2 = std::move(mc);
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/RjcHF3)

As for the second part - there is no way to force a construct like these:

```
MyClass mc2(mc); //Move, not copy
//-or-
MyClass mc2 = mc; //Move, not copy
```

to move. If you want to move from an lvalue (and `mc` is indeed an lvalue), you have to use `std::move` (or another cast to rvalue) explicitly.

There is one thing you *could* do, but it would be a dirty hack, make the code unintuitive and be a great source for bugs. You could add an overload of the copy constructor (and copy assignment operator) taking a non-const reference, which would do the move. Basically something like `std::auto_ptr` used to do before it was rightfully deprecated. But it would never pass code review with me, for example. If you want to move, just `std::move`.

---

A few side notes:

- Calling `delete` or `delete[]` on a null pointer is guaranteed to be a no-op, so you can safely drop the `if` from your destructor.
- It's generally preferable to use `std::copy` instead of `memcpy` in C++ code, you don't have to worry about getting the `sizeof` right

Comment: Oh, it works for now, thanks. And what about second question part? About constructor and assignment

Comment: @Xanx I assumed from the question that you had already tried `MyClass mc2 = std::move(mc);` Why did you immediately jump to the conclusion that `&&` was necessary?

Comment: @Xanx I edited in a way you *could* force the move, but *please don't.* It's ugly.

Comment: @Angew thanks, I see now. Actually I do not need to force it, I just wanted to check whther it is possible or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can force move semantics, if you delete the copy constructor and the assignment operator

```
MyClass(const MyClass& src)= delete;
void operator=(const MyClass& src) = delete;
```

in this case the provided move constructor or move assignment operator will be picked.

Answer (score 0):

**Rewrite your class a bit with some comments.** Look over it, you might notice a few things you missed. Like:

- in `MyClass(size_t c)` not checking for `c != 0`.
- in `void operator=(const MyClass& src)` not `delete[] data;` *(if exists)* before reallocating.

And some other tiny details.Hope your compiler can handle this.

```
class MyClass {
private:
    // initialize memebers directly
    int* data = nullptr;
    size_t count = 0;
public:
    // default empty contructor
    MyClass() = default;
    // destructor
    ~MyClass() {
        *this = nullptr; // use operator = (nullptr_t)
    }
    // allow nullptr construct
    MyClass(nullptr_t):MyClass() {}
    // allow nullptr assignment (for clearing)
    MyClass& operator = (nullptr_t) {
        if(data) {
            delete[] data;
            data = nullptr;
        }
        count = 0;
        return *this;
    }
    // chain to default constructor, redundant in this case
    MyClass(size_t c):MyClass() {
        // maybe size_t is 0?
        if(count = c) {
            data = new int[count];
        }
    }
    // chain to default constructor, redundant in this case
    MyClass(MyClass&& src):MyClass() {
        *this = std::move(src); // forward to move assignment
    }
    MyClass& operator=(MyClass&& src) {
        // don't swap with self
        if(&src != this) {
            // it's better to swap and let src destroy when it feels like it.
            // I always write move contructor and assignment to swap data.
            // it's gonna be destroyed anyway, or not...
            std::swap(src.data, data);
            std::swap(src.count, count);
        }
        return *this;
    }
    MyClass(const MyClass& src):MyClass() {
        *this = src; // forward to copy assignment
    }
    MyClass& operator = (const MyClass& src) {
        // don't copy to self
        if(&src != this) {
            // delete first
            if(data) {
                delete[] data;
                data = nullptr;
            }

            // now reallocate
            if(count = src.count) {
                data = new int[count];
                memcpy(data, src.data, sizeof(int)* count);
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }
    // easy way to use the object in a if(object) to test if it has content
    explicit operator bool() const {
        return data && count;
    }
    // same as above but made for if(!object) to test if empty
    bool operator !() const {
        return !data || !count;
    }
public:
    int* get_data() const {
        return data;
    }
    size_t get_count() const {
        return count;
    }
    // add more custom methods
};
```

Now to move you do this:

```
MyClass object1; // default construct
MyClass object1(5); // construct with capacity
MyClass object2(object1); // copy constructor
MyClass object3(std::move(object1)); // move constructor
object2 = object1; // copy assignment
object3 = std::move(object1); // move constructor
std::swap(object2, object3); // swap the two
object2 = nullptr; // to empty it
if(object1); // bool cast
```